# How does react solve this diffing algorithm issue?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, reactjs

I am currently building a new diffing loop for my own reactive components framework.

It currently uses array indexes in the diffing loop which turns out to be a bit problematic in some cases. For example if you have a list of nodes and add something in the middle of the list every element after that will be re rendered because the diffing algorithm will think the element has changed because of its shift in position.
Thats why now im going towards using an object key approach to reference objects of current or previous revisions. So i want every element to have a reference key which is stable across revisions. But i dont see how to implement this for elements which are created on the fly for example nodes that are created inside a for loop. Anyone willing to help me out or maybe explain how react solves this problem?

Thank you in advance.

To demonstrate the problem:
[Array indexes ouf of sync](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7MQn.png)

Comment: Please provide your code/solution so far

Comment: *"How does react solve this diffing algorithm issue?"* The developer has to provide the `key`. It's not clear to me what your issue is.

Comment: The problem is that keys have to be generated on the fly. For example if you have a for loop in your template like in angular and lets say we generate 2 revisions to computate diff algorithm on. How do we generate a key for each for loop item that stays the same across multiple revisions? It is important because if they are not the same then the diff system will think that the element should be rendered again, because the element key is different.

Comment: *"The problem is that keys have to be generated on the fly."* As I said, React expects the developer to provide the key. Usually objects that are rendered in a list have a unique ID, which is used as key.

Comment: Ok. But if no key is provided does it fall back to use array indexes for matching elements?

Comment: AFAIK it will use the position of the element in the list, yes.